# How can one compare these groups?

Tags: ab-test

I have two dataset A and B. We have 93 persons in A and 88 in B.

Dataset A contains number of person who had made a payment. So `A` is

```
number of payments      number of persons made that payment
1                       93  
2                       41
3                       35
4                       28
5                       20
6                       14
7                       7
8                       4
```

Similar way with dataset B.

My question is this: How can I calculate if A has a higher performance than B, ie if we have significant more person in A who make a payment compared to B.

Comment: Poisson GLM regression

Comment: Thanks for the response, Could you explain more details how to setup a model for Poisson GLM ?

Comment: Isn't computing the mean of numbers of payment per person not what you need ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to find out if "*more persons* in A made a payment than in B"? Isn't the *number of payments* more important than the number of persons? Or the total amount payed?

Comment: That is correct.